# Restrict access to Lightweight Grid

Tags: lightweight-grid

When using the default configuration of the [Lightweight Grid Manager](http://www.wolfram.com/lightweight-grid-manager/), anyone connected to the same internal network where the grid severs are can launch kernels on the grid.

What possibilities are there to restrict access to the Lightweight Grid, and how can these restrictions be enabled?  Is IPFiler the only way?

Comment: Contact support@wolfram.com and mention my name so I can get in touch with you to discuss your needs on this.

Comment: Sorry but I use our grid in a completely isolated technology environment where I've never had to think about restricting access.  I will give it some thought to see if I can think of with a workaround.

Comment: @Jagra Thanks for taking a look.  My environment isn't open either, but still many more people have access to it than who would be using the service.

Comment: @Joel Thank you for the help!  We only started to use the Lightweight Grid a day ago, so at this moment I can't really ask for any extra features.  I really just wanted to learn how to use the existing functionality.  If IPFilter is the only way to restrict access, then I won't spend time looking for additional ways.  We'll simply try to use IPFilter first and see if it is convenient.

Comment: @Joel I'd like to note just one small thing about the installation process:  if one doesn't read the Windows/Linux sections (only the OS X ones), there's nothing in the docs noting that Java needs to be installed before trying to install Lightweight Grid.  It seems to install fine, but when it opens the web browser, the admin page doesn't load.  It would be helpful to put a little note in the installation instruction about the Java requirement.

Comment: @Szabolcs, LWG uses the Java from the Mathematica layout, in a sense it is already installed. If you could follow up with me via support that would be great, I want to understand what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gridMathematica 8 (the current version), IPFilter is the only way to restrict access.

Future versions could provide additional ways, particularly through the kernel initialization code in the Service configuration. Right now there is no information provided to the launched kernel about the launch request that could be used to restrict access, but that could be added.